# Slider with thumbnail navigation and pagination for thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I searched a lot about it but couldn't find any. Well, I need a slider with a thumbnail navigation and that thumbnail navigation should have a pagination. I want to show only four thumbnails but in total I have 16, so I want a pagination for the thumbnails. [Please see this image for better understanding of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCjVh.jpg)

```
              <div id="gallery-wrapper">

                <div id="viewer-wrapper">

                    <div id="gallery-viewer">
                        <img alt="Placeholder" src="images/placeholder.png">
                    </div><!-- #gallery-viewer -->

                </div><!-- #viewer-wrapper" -->

                <div id="viewer-nav">
                    <a id="gallery-viewer-next" href="#">next</a>
                    <a id="gallery-viewer-prev" href="#">previous</a>
                </div><!-- #viewer-nav -->

                <div id="thumbs-nav">
                    <a id="gallery-next" href="#">next</a><a id="gallery-prev" href="#">previous</a><p id="gallery-pos">page 1 of 2</p>
                </div>

                <div id="thumbs-wrapper">

                    <div id="gallery">

                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img alt="Wasteland" src="gallery/thumbs/wasteland.jpg">
                        </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img alt="Woods" src="gallery/thumbs/woods.jpg">
                        </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img alt="Tree Path" src="gallery/thumbs/treepath.jpg">
                        </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img alt="Cobblestone Road" src="gallery/thumbs/stoneroad.jpg">
                        </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img alt="Street" src="gallery/thumbs/street.jpg">
                        </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img alt="Tree Path" src="gallery/thumbs/treepath2.jpg">
                        </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img alt="Desert" src="gallery/thumbs/desert.jpg">
                        </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img alt="Misty Woods" src="gallery/thumbs/mistywoods.jpg">
                        </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img alt="Woodsy Stairs" src="gallery/thumbs/woodsystairs.jpg">
                        </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img alt="Snowy Trees" src="gallery/thumbs/snowytrees.jpg">
                        </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img alt="Street" src="gallery/thumbs/street2.jpg">
                        </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img alt="City" src="gallery/thumbs/city.jpg">
                        </div><!-- .thumbnail -->

                    </div><!-- #gallery -->

                </div><!-- #thumbs-wrapper -->

            </div>




<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jfollow.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ImageGallery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // set up the gallery
            $('#gallery').gallery({
                'rows': 1,
                'cols': 5
            });

            // some extra interface stuff... pay no attention to the man behind the curtain
            var gallery = $('#gallery-wrapper'), setup = $('#setup-wrapper');
            setup.hide();
            $('#show-setup').click(function(){
                gallery.fadeOut(400,function(){
                    setup.fadeIn();
                });
                return false;
            });
            $('#show-gallery').click(function(){
                setup.fadeOut(400,function(){
                    gallery.fadeIn();
                });
                return false;
            });
            $('#nav-wrapper').jfollow('#followbox', 20);
        </script>
```

I have tried a lot and I found this example:

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Basic-jQuery-Gallery-with-Paginated-Thumbnail-Navigation-ImageGallery-js/

But how can I create a numbered pagination like "1,2,3,4,5" instead of having previous or next buttons? I can't figure it out.

Comment: I have tried please see above link. I have edited

Comment: Now I've posted the code as well. I can't create a numbering pagination in this code